# How do you make a sub menu persist in android when scrolling the page

Tags: android, menu, scrollview

Kinda like how facebook pages in android does it where they persist the tab bar on to the header and back to the scroll view when you scroll down. What can I use to build this out?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't include the view that you want to persist in the scroll view. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/receivedTasksButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/task_type_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textOff="Received"
            android:textOn="Received"
            android:checked="true" />
        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/sentTasksButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/task_type_button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textOff="Sent"
            android:textOn="Sent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/tasklistscrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_above="@+id/newTaskButton" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/taskList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/newTaskButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/newrecording" />


</RelativeLayout>
```